# How to implement states that aren't mutually exclusive

Tags: design-patterns

I'm working on a GUI application using the MVC pattern, but the controller has proven to be much more complicated than I originally thought it would be.

The application has options which determine how the operations in the action listeners function, so I started to use the state design pattern. But then I realized that the options(states) aren't mutually exclusive. You can have two different states at the same time.

All implementations of the State pattern assume states are mutually exclusive. How can I implement this in such a way that allows for multiple states to be active at the same time, and allows me to add new states later on without changing code?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific with your examples? You don't need to reveal what you're doing, but it would help if you described some use cases for changing state and how that should affect the system.

Comment: How did you get that deep in coding before realizing the options aren't mutually exclusive? To me, that points to a flaw in the dev process. I mean you have architectural patterns lined up, even before the requirements are fully understood. I was more Agile previously so I made similar mistakes, but these days I see the benefit of more design thought and especially more requirements and scope analysis up front.

Comment: Use composition (read about Composition vs Inheritance etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you you have multiple state types but you haven't recognized them all yet. So you started out capturing them in a single set. You may for example have this enum for a job's state:

{ Queued, Running, PausePending, Paused, Resumed, CancelPending, Canceled, Aborted, Finished }

And this may look OK and complete. Until you notice the job is still running after the user issued a cancel request until it is actually canceled. So what is its state in the meantime really?

It appears that raising a cancel request is independent from the job's state, hence it is not a job state. It is a job state change request.

So you really have two types:

JobState { Queued, Running, Paused, Canceled, Aborted, Finished }

JobStateChangeRequest { None, Pause, Resume, Cancel }

I suspect you have a similar issue on your hands.

Answer (score 3):

The [state design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) uses composition to maintain a current state object and delegate it any state specific requests. The state object has a class derived from an abstract state class.  This design indeed assumes that states are mutually exclusive.

If the states of your application are not mutually exclusive, you either have several [state machines](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/state-machine-diagrams.html), or have composite states.

**1.Multiple state machines**

If the state machines are completely independent, and each state machine is responsible for a mutually exclusive set of requests,  apply several times the state design pattern, with independent state objects. [Separation of concerns](https://effectivesoftwaredesign.com/2012/02/05/separation-of-concerns/) (two state machines) makes this very easy to maintain.  Example:

```
class StateA {     // first family of states
public:  
    void doUpdate()=0;    // handling one kind of requests 
}; 
class StateA1 : public StateA { 
    ...
}; 

class StateB {     // second family of states 
public:  
    void doDelete()=0;   // handling another kind of requests
}; 
class StateB1 : public StateB { 
    ...
}; 

class Context {
private: 
    StateA *a;    // independent states 
    StateB *b;  
...
};
```

If the state machines are independent, but the unfortunately the handling of the requests is dependent on the combination of the states, this technique will not work in general.  Then you could:

- use the state design pattern, but create combined concrete states (with or without sub-classing, or eventually using multiple inheritance).  This will be painful not only for implementing new combinations each time you add a new state, but also for managing all the new state transitions.
- combine the state pattern, with the [decorator pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/decorator-pattern.html) or the [strategy pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html).  This could avoid some redundant code, but will still leave state transitions horrible to maintain.

**2. Nested state machines**

With composite states, some main states are clearly mutually exclusive.  However,  some of them have a sub-state (which can be dependent of the main state).  In this case, you need nested state machines:

- the brute force approach would be to work with a classic state pattern, but to subclass further the main states that require it.  Again, it will be painful to maintain the state transitions every time you'd add anew sub-state.
- it could be feasible to implement the main state using a the state pattern and implement a sub-state in the concrete main states that require it. This approach is again less coupled and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

What might be of use to you is [Chain of Responsibility Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern). You model each state as one link in the chain, and then send events their way. That way, more than one link can react to an event.

Unfortunately, without more details on what you are trying to do, I cannot provide more details.